# MySQL triggers - I've set them up to populate a new table but need a way to populate from existing data

Tags: mysql, triggers

Title says most of it - I've setup a new table that's populated by other tables via triggers.

Obviously that new table has no data yet - I need to find a way to get it populated with the existing data rather than just new stuff as it comes in.

Triggers are update/create/delete so I could update a field somewhere to add a space at the end then remove it, but that seems a little...weird

Any ideas please?  I've searched on here and can't see one.

example would be table posts, insert trigger then populates table posts_stats with a count(*)

It's specifically to trigger the triggers from existing data.

Thanks!

Comment: Apart from the question being to broad: Stop and just **don't**. Data should be kept redundancy free to avoid the possibilities of inconsistencies. So writing a sum or a count or similar over one table into another isn't a good thing to do. If you need the sum or count or anything, you can always query it and get the **right** result. For convenience you can create a view that stores such a query so you don't have to repeat it every time.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment.  I understand your concerns and have thought through the whole process already and we need this for performance reasons.  It's not a great idea I know, but as DBA I have no choice other than to get the devs to do it in code.  It doesn't actually matter if it's a few out (I feel silly even typing that)I can think of a few ways to populate it so I'll do that but was hoping someone here had a bright idea I'd not come up with.  Thanks again!

Comment: How about `create view`? I will add in below

Answer (score 0):

I suggest Create View.
Reason:
MySQL supports views, including updatable views. Views are stored queries that when invoked produce a result set. A view acts as a virtual table. (Mysql Manual)

I will Explaination based on case:

Create table:

```
CREATE TABLE `sample_user` (
  `id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` enum('F','M') DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=ascii
```

Insert Sample Data:

```
insert into `sample_user` (`id`, `name`, `gender`) values('1','Aalona','F');
insert into `sample_user` (`id`, `name`, `gender`) values('2','Abbie','F');
insert into `sample_user` (`id`, `name`, `gender`) values('3','Brielle','F');
insert into `sample_user` (`id`, `name`, `gender`) values('4','Abigail','F');
insert into `sample_user` (`id`, `name`, `gender`) values('5','Caleb','M');
insert into `sample_user` (`id`, `name`, `gender`) values('6','Damian','M');
```

Sample Data:

[image: sample-data]

Syntax Create View:

```
CREATE VIEW sample_view
AS SELECT gender,COUNT(*) total FROM `sample_user` GROUP BY gender
```

In Sqlyogeditor will look like this:

[image: SQL data]

After that you can select from that view.

```
SELECT * FROM sample_view
```

Result:

[image: example view]

Further Read:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/views.html

Comment: Hi - thanks for your in-depth answer!  The problem is that for a very few users that are subscribed to a large number of $things in our application, the performance is terrible, which is why I was trying to build a way to have a stats table to help with that.  From what you, and others, have said I'm thinking about it the wrong way round.  It's not an index problem for the majority of users, and adding one would slow *them* down.  I'll have another think (maybe we do it in code in then end).  Thanks to everyone for the help!  Really appreciated!

Comment: If accuracy is not really important, you can create a cron job. I do this for calculating best selling product OR "Top Global" User in some games. Good Luck on your job :)

Comment: I did consider a cron job, thanks.  I've bugged the devs to work out how to do it a better way in code.  They hate me now :)